# Automate translation for personal use

Tags: python, web-scraping, translation

I would like to translate a few hundred words for an application I'm writing. This is a simple, one-off project, so I'm not willing to pay for the the google translate API.
Is there another web service which will do this?
Another idea is to just send a search to Google, and scrape the result from the first result. For example, google 'translate food to spanish'.
However, the page is a mess of obfuscated javascript, and I would need help scraping the result.
I think python would be good for this, but any language will do.

Comment: I suspect they make it purposefully hard to retrieve the results, because they want you to pay for their API!

Comment: This isn't really a question suitable for SO. If it's just a few hundred words, then I'd probably just be tempted to type them into the page and save them

Comment: You should go over your [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1123789/muricula?tab=questions) and [accept some answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that people will answer your questions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Microsoft Translator API](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/) or use [Google Translator Toolkit](http://translate.google.com/toolkit/list?hl=en#translations/active). And unless this is a toy application, get a real person to translate it, not a machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing using python with the googletrans module:

```
from googletrans import Translator
text = "YOUR TEXT GOES HERE"
destination = "THE LANGUAGE YOU WANT TO TRANSLATE TO GOES HERE"
trans = Translator()
t = trans.translate(text, dest=destination)
```

It is free, unlimited and uses the Google Translate Ajax API.

To translate to Spanish, set "destination" to "es".

Here is a list of all languages and their codes:

> https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages

Answer (score 0):

Or go to MicrosoftTranslator.com, and paste your text in one box, have it translate and cut and paste the result?

Failing that, the MS Translator API can be used for up to 2 million characters a month for free...so maybe use that?